# Battleship Code - Changing List keys

Tags: python

I'm trying to alternate my battleship game in Codecademy but I'm not able to change the "0" to "X".

This is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint

board = []
board_size = 7
turns = 0

def printboard(board):
    for i in range(board_size):
        board = (["0"] * 7)
        print (" ".join(board))
    return board

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, 5)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, 5)

printboard(board)
ship_row = random_row(board)
print(ship_row)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print(ship_col)

for turns in range(4):
    if turns <= 5:
        guess_row = input("Guess row: ")
        guess_row = int(guess_row)
        guess_col = input("Guess col: ")
        guess_col = int(guess_col)
        if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
            print("You won!")
            break
        else:
            if ((guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 6) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 6)):
                print("Not in map")
            elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == 'X'):
                print("You guessed that already.")
            else:
                print("Missed")
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = 'X'
                print (turns + 1)
    elif turns == 3:
        print("Game Over!")
```

This error comes up:

```
elif(board[[guess_row][guess_col]] == 'X'):
```

IndexError: list index out of range

How can I place the X in the site where I shoot?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of problems with your code.

Firstly, `board` is an empty list, hence accessing `board[[guess_row][guess_col]` will always throw an `IndexError: list index out of range` exception.

Secondly, you have a global variable `board` but yet you pass it as an input into `printboard(board)`. Decide on whether or not you want to use the global variable. Also, `printboard` returns `board` but this is not assigned anywhere.

Thirdly, you never create a full board at all. You merely create and print one row of 7 zeroes which is never saved.

Unfortunately, there is a significant amount of code rewriting to be done to make your battleship game work. StackOverflow typically frowns upon rewriting large chunks of code.

Just to help you get started and solve this first exception, simply change the start of your code:

```
from random import randint

board_size = 7
board = [["0"] * 7 for i in range(board_size)]
turns = 0

def printboard():
    for row in board:
        print ' '.join(row)
```

You can run it [here](https://repl.it/JDQU/1).